# Operators (operands?) as Parameters

Tags: php, html, parameters

I am trying to avoid duplicating my code by checking the variable if it is a certain operator.

Basically..

```
$op = $_POST['operator'];
$x = 5;
$y = 2;
$result = $x /* $op instead of '+'/'-'/'*'/'/'/'%' */ $y;
```

Is this possible or will I have to send the operator as a String and duplicate the code per operator type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a lot safer to do something like this:

```
$x = 5;
$y = 2;

switch($_POST['operator']){
    case '+':
        $result = $x + $y;
        break;
    case '-':
        $result = $x - $y;
        break;
    case '*':
        $result = $x*$y;
        break;
    case '/':
        $result = $x/$y;
        break;
    case '%':
        $result = $x % $y;
        break;
     default:
        $result = 'Operator not supported';
}
```

Something along those lines.

Comment: quite lenghty, but still better than the `eval()` IMHO

Answer (score 1):

Ahem.  You can `eval`.

```
$result = eval("$x $op $y");
```

But this is **DANGEROUS** and you should sanitize your variables with great care.  There is a saying that goes something like "If your problem requires use of `eval`, then the problem is wrong."  Something like that.  It's almost certainly preferable to do something like this:

```
function apply_op($x, $y, $op) {
    switch ($op) {
    case '+': return $x + $y;
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: All the parameters will be properly sanitized. Thank you! :)

Comment: And eval is often a sign that you're doing something wrong - which does weight much more than dangerous - even in caps and bold ;)

Comment: Hrm. I guess a switch statement is much safer -- though not as clean as I would have hoped. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @Dietrich Epp: Depends on the point of view. Being wrong, consequently, and especially, automatically by writing code that commands machines, is a really bad idea. In day-to-day life, that varies, sure.

Comment: I agree with @harke on this one. Use a switch instead.

Comment: @Mike: If you read the entire answer, you'll see that I also recommend a switch.

Answer (score 0):

you can make this:

```
$operators = array("+", "-","*","%","/"); 
$op = $_POST["operator"]; 
if(in_array($op, $operators)) {
    echo eval("$x $op $y");
} else {
    echo "Operator not supported";
}
```

Comment: using eval is quite dangerous in this case because the $op is a user input. User can then enter anything including executing some dangerous PHP codes.